# Getting decennial census data using acs in r

Tags: r, acs

I'm trying to get data from 2000 and 2010:

```
acs.fetch(endyear="2000",span="0", LA_tract, variable="H002_001", dataset="sf1")
```

Also tried:

```
acs.fetch(endyear="2000",span="0", LA_tract, table.name="H002", dataset="sf1")
```

(LA_tract is the geography)

I get an error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

The variable/table number is correct...
The function and key work fine with ACS data - just not decade data.

I would appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: Should have mentioned: LA_tract is the geography - work fine with ACS data

Comment: I don't have an acs key so I cannot really test it but could it be as easy as using  variable = "H002_001" with quotes?

Comment: No it isn't.. thank you though

Comment: Well - maybe it was one problem - but then I get a different error:
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Answer (score 0):

span is the number of years in the survey.  I've seen 5 and 3 and 1, but not 0.